# Visual Studio Debugging Property

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

I have a label in asp.net.
I am using Visual Studio. How do I go about tracking the value of:

```
    lblInvalid.Visible
```

While I am debugging. I need to track the value through out the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it under watch variables (debug->window->watch) or check it's value in immediate window (debug->window->immediate).